# How can I call a function in clojure and get a result?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to implement an amazon aws binding with Clojure, so that I can search for a book by sending an isbn and get an xml report of it. I am then trying to retrieve the salesrank and book title from the report. Here is what I am trying to use: https://github.com/FreeAgent/clj-amazon

Instead of using REPL, I made a core2.clj inside the src folder and added this code into it:

```
(ns clj_amazon.core2
(:use clj-amazon.core)
(:use clj-amazon.product-advertising)
(:gen-class))

(defn -main [& args]

(def ACCESS-KEY "my access code")

(def SECRET-KEY "my secret key" )

(def ASSOCIATE-ID "my id")

(def gibson-opus-search (with-signer (ACCESS-KEY, SECRET-KEY) (item-search :search-index "Books", :keywords "Neuromancer", :associate-tag ASSOCIATE-ID,    :condition "New")))

(gibson-opus-search)

)
```

If I remove

```
(gibson-opus-search)
```

and run "lein run" in the command line, I get no errors. I have the correct access key/secret key, and it seems that the code is working fine. But I also get no report printed. I'm new to Clojure, so I'm not understanding what I should do next. I tried to call the function with

```
(gibson-opus-search)
```

, but then i get this error: wrong number of args(0) passed to persistentarraymap. How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What results are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `gibson-opus-search` with `def` which is for for assigning values, not defining functions.  You need to define it with `defn` then call it with the right number of arguments.